# Is there a way to generate a VAPID key in Laravel for WebPush Notifications?

Tags: laravel, push-notification, notifications, web-push

I'm trying a developing a notifcation function in Laravel. I've tried generating a VAPID key for my Laravel Project. After I'm done entering

> **php artisan webpush:vapid**

in my CLI,
the result I get is

> *RuntimeException Unable to create the key*.

.

Answer (score 0):

If the remaining error message has `OpenSSL` e.g:

```
Jose\Component\Core\Util\ECKey::createECKeyUsingOpenSSL("P-256")
```

you would need to download and install OpenSSL